# Update MySQL table based on inner join and handling duplicate entries from query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table Events:

[image]

and a table Users:

[image]

I want to go over the events table and replace appearances of emails in the `name` column with the corresponding name from the Users table.
So for example, the third and fourth row in Events should inherit the name john.

**Now the events table has a primary key on all four columns.**

So notice lines three and four would become duplicates upon performing this code:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

UPDATE events
        INNER JOIN Users
            ON events.`name` = users.`email`
            SET events.`name` = users.`name`;
```

Is it possible to perform the replacement and delete those duplicate values when they arise? I also thought it may be possible to use something similar to a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and change the values of one of the columns in a duplicate row to something indicative, then remove the row.

Comment: Any ideas, please?

Comment: I think the table design is poor. I tried something on sql fiddle: [Trial demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/839e3f/3)

Comment: If you are looking for a way to remove duplicate see [mysql delete duplicate rows](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/)